# Why the footer doesn't appear at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

Below you can see my code. It seems that the footer is "stuck" at the bottom of h2_c div not at the bottom of .content div as it should. Why that?
I tried to use positioning but it doesn't work.

Thak You.

```css
.header {
  background: #a7a7a7;
  min-height: 700px;
  position: relative;
}
.content {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 70px auto 0 auto;
}
.h2_c {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.one {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}
.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.two {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: green;
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.three {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}
.h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.p {
  color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 20px 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.span {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 20px;
}
.footer {
  border-top: 4px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content">
  <h2 class="h2_c">Content</h2>
  <div class="one">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="span">Text 1</span>
      <h2 class="h2">Some really cool text</h2>
      <p class="p">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="span">Text 2</span>
      <h2 class="h2">Some really cool text</h2>
      <p class="p">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="span">Text 3</span>
      <h2 class="h2">Some really cool text</h2>
      <p class="p">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: You might find these articles helpful: [Force Element To Self-Clear](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) and [Clearing Floats](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your floated "really cool text" sections are escaping the `.content` section, since (by default) floats aren't considered when computing the container's height.

Add `overflow: auto` to `.content` to create a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) and fix this.

```css
.header {
  background: #a7a7a7;
  min-height: 700px;
  position: relative;
}
.content {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 70px auto 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.h2_c {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.one {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}
.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.two {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: green;
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.three {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}
.h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.p {
  color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 20px 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.span {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 20px;
}
.footer {
  border-top: 4px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content">
  <h2 class="h2_c">Content</h2>
  <div class="one">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="span">Text 1</span>
      <h2 class="h2">Some really cool text</h2>
      <p class="p">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="span">Text 2</span>
      <h2 class="h2">Some really cool text</h2>
      <p class="p">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="span">Text 3</span>
      <h2 class="h2">Some really cool text</h2>
      <p class="p">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Technically it's called [Block Formatting Context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) (BFC), not float context.

Comment: @Oriol Thanks. Corrected and linked.

Comment: @Paul Roub, Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Because when you float an element you get it out of the normal html flow. If you insert a line like:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Right below your 3 floating `div's` it will work as you expect.

You can do the same using `:after` pseudoelement with `clear: both`property but I'm just a fan of the first choice (for a bit more cross "old" browsers compatibility).

Adding `overflow:hidden` works also but I don't like that aproach as... what if you don't want to hide the overflow?